# Oracle SQL how to convert '1/15/1976' to 19760115 DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a code like this

```
SELECT to_date(to_char('1/15/1976','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM DUAL;
```

The error is showing ORA-01722: invalid number,

How can I fix this error to show 19760115

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('01/15/1976','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Your welcome! `to_date` converts a string into a date, and `to_char` converts a date into a string. I often mistype this myself.